# SharePoint online list Allow multiple selections

Tags: powerapps-forms

I need help with Allowing multiple selections in SharePoint online. I have a lookup column in this list, and I have customised this list with PowerApps. It won't save the multi-sections and gives the below error message.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the value of ThisItem.Lookup? Can you add screenshot of column settings? If it is a multiple selection allowed "combo box" Control, you should set the DefaultSelectedItems property instead of Default property.

Comment: I added the screenshot, in PowerApps, is this true that in PowerApps I need to remove this and add the combo box?

Comment: If you have multiple selection column in SharePoint, Power Apps should automatically add combo box control for it.

Comment: Still shows as a Choice control :(

Comment: Can you confirm if it is a drop down control or combo box control? (or any other?)

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP its a combo box.